# Randomly choose an option from the dropdown box and click to activate an another function that uses onChange in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, click, html-select

I will add a script `onChange` linked to this dropdown box (`id="select-box-1"`), for when I choose one of the options, it will be activated.

The button `id="botao-do-jogo-aleatorio-1"` randomly chooses one of the options from the selection box.

But currently when I click on the button for random choice, the select bar appears the chosen option, but it does not activate `onChange` scripts because there was no action.

How could I make this selection of the checkbox but generating a click instead of just setting the value like `.selectedIndex` Is doing?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
        <script id="random-number">
            function generateRandomIntegerInRange(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column left">
                <form id="jogo-aleatorio-1" action="" method="post">
                    <button class="button" id="botao-do-jogo-aleatorio-1" style="width: 100%;" onclick="funcao_jogo_aleatorio_1()">Partida Aleatória 1</button>
                </form>
                <script id="script-da-caixa-de-selecao-suspensa-1">
                    function funcao_jogo_aleatorio_1() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('jogo-aleatorio-1');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){ 
                            e.preventDefault();
                            document.getElementById("select-box-1").selectedIndex = generateRandomIntegerInRange(1, document.querySelectorAll("dl dt").length);
                        };
                    }
                </script>
                <form action="" method="post" id="formulario-radar-1">
                    <div id="caixa-suspensa-1">
                        <input type="text" id="barra-de-texto-para-radar-1" style="width: 283px;">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <select id="select-box-1" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value="" market=""></option>
                    <option value="home" market="away">journey</option>
                    <option value="hotel" market="party">events</option>
                </select>
                <dl style="color:white;font-weight:bold;;overflow:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;">
                    <dt>journey</option>
                    <dt>events</option>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the answer

```
let a = document.querySelectorAll(".dl dt");

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
  // code here and use 'this'
 };
};
```

Use a **for** loop to check every input elements, *or you can't access it*.
Then **insert** functions, objects or array in *// code here*, and use **"this"** selector to work with the selected input.

Comment: Hi @OuterGuy But if the choice of the option in the drop-down box is done with random number, how would it be defined inside the looping? **Sorry for my lack of knowledge**, but I couldn't understand how to proceed. I couldn't add my code inside your referral.

Comment: I don't understand your request, post an image in your question or explains it in a better way.

Comment: When I use the ```selectedIndex``` to choose the option from the selection box, the chosen value appears selected in the selection box. But when I make this selection manually, a ```change``` occurs and activates an ```onChange function```. In case when I choose from ```selectedIndex``` this ```onChange``` is not activated.

Comment: My answer is correct, you need to for loop every input, or you can't access it. "onchange" method doesn't work because it's not the right command.
Use a for loop and insert function, object or array in // code here, and use "this" to work with the selected input.